# Only allow localhost with own filter, not with catalina

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I'm making a Java webapplication. This webapplication is embedded in another application, and should only accept request from the localhost.
I saw different solutions which use the org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve dependency in their solutions, this is not applicable in my solution.

I'm trying to make my own Filter to do this, I get following configuration in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.search.watson.AccessFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I use following implementation:

```
public class AccessFilter implements Filter {

    private PropertiesHelper propertiesHelper = new PropertiesHelper();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletRequest.getRemoteHost().equals(propertiesHelper.getProperty("searchAllowedIP", "127.0.0.1"))) {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing happened");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

My IP address of my server is 10.254.201.53, when I navigate to 10.254.201.53:8080/watson, this needs to block, when I access the search engine inside the application (10.254.201.53:8080/search), this needs to work.

But this doesn't seem to work, what can I do to make this work?

Comment: If only for localhost you can use `servletRequest.getLocalAddr().equals(servletRequest.getRemoteAddr())`

Comment: I edited my question to make the problem more clear, it shows why this solution doesn't work

Comment: Get you server ip address and compare it with requesters ip address and if they are same proceed the filter chain. Don't compare ip with `127.0.0.1` because you won't get ip address as localhost even if request is made from one. Also you might wanna change the url pattern of the filter to allow m block `watson` or `search`